# Error while looping pymongo object

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

I have a collection like.

```
{
    "id" : 101,
    "name" : "ragav",
    "address" : "143 karnadaka",
    "products" : [
                    {
                        "id" : 2,
                        "name" : "AA",
                        "amount" : "150"
                    },
                    {
                        "id" : 4,
                        "name" : "BB",
                        "amount" : "15"
                    },
                    {
                        "id" : 6,
                        "name" : "CC",
                        "amount" : "210"
                    },

                ]
}
```

I need to find a record in this collection based on product. I running the following query.

**Query**

```
 db.Response.find(
                  {"products.id":2},
                 {"products.id.$":1,"id":1,"name":1,"address":1}
              )
```

In my mongo terminal i got the output.   But i accessing through python using pymongo2.8  when i taring to iterate pymongo object  getting an error like this.

> database error: Executor error: InternalError: ambiguous positional
>   projection

what is the reason for this error?   How it solve??

Answer (score 0):

If a positional operator appears in a projection or update, and there were multiple array matches against the document, MongoDB will issue an error.

so basically the issue is with the $ in the products.id.$

and this is an expected behavior. please refer https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-14662 for more info and examples.